# Should I use inline bathroom fans?

Tags: bathroom, fan, exhaust-vent, exhaust-fan

I'm building a new full bathroom in my basement and I also have an existing full bathroom without an exhaust fan.  The sizes are 207 ft3 and 470 ft3 respectively. I was initially thinking of buying those high quality Panasonic fans but then I found about the inline fans and they might make sense for me since my bathrooms are almost on top of each other and they can share the exterior exhaust grill anyway.  There's also enough space between the walls for that stuff to go through, so that's not a concern.

Do people have experience with these inline bathroom fans?  How does one calculate the needed capacity?  Anything I should be aware of?

Edit: Here's an article about this:

http://www.bathroomfanexperts.com/article.php/inline-fans-for-bathroom-ventilation-/?id=44

Comment: Are you thinking of using one fan for both bathrooms, or one for each?

Comment: Single fan after a Y.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'll answer my own question a month after the installation.  Inline are great, especially high-quality ones such as Fantech.  Highly recommended.

Comment: How did you wire these? Is there a 3 way switch in each bathroom?